# How to construct grammatically correct sentences containing the word "want"?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, get-be

Is there any difference between these three sentences? Which one is correct or sounds more naturally?
1. You wanted us to get caught. 
2. You wanted us to be caught. 
3. You wanted to get us caught.

Comment: All three are technically "correct".  #1 is the most idiomatic.

Comment: Agreed, all three are OK.  I think 3. has a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example one and two mean the same thing. You wanted us to get caught [by someone else]. Example three means something different. You wanted [you yourself] to [do something to] get us caught.

All three are grammatical  I can't actually picture a scenario where a character would use example three, but examples one and two are fairly common, with example number one being the most popular usage.

Comment: While 1 and 2 seem to exclude “you” from “us” (I.e., “you” wasn’t part of the group that was caught) in 3 “you” is more likely to be part of “us”.  (E.g. we coerced you into sneaking out of the house  with us, but since you didn’t really want to do it in the first place you made some “accidental” noise and Dad heard us.  So you wanted to get us caught)